# Java inheritance and Scope of variable

Tags: java, inheritance, scope

The Program is:

```
class A
{
   int i = 10;
}
class B extends A
{
   int j = 20;
}
class C extends B
{
   int k = 30;
}
class D extends C
{
   int m = 40;
}

public class asg2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       A[] a = {new A(),new B(), new C(), new D()};

    System.out.println(a[3].i); //No error!!!
    System.out.println(a[2].j); //throws error 
    System.out.println(a[1].k); //throws error (Understood why error)
    System.out.println(a[0].m); //throws error (Understood why error)
}
```

}

I understand why the last two throw error.
But I dont understand why the 2nd print statement throws error. 
And first one runs smoothly.

```
asg2.java:29: error: cannot find symbol         
System.out.println(a[2].j);                                    
                       ^
symbol:   variable j                    
location: class A
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler does not see the element `a[2]` of type `C`. It sees it of type `A` because that's the type of the declared array. Hence it cannot accept accessing a field that belongs to a subclass of `A`. If you cast the element to `C`, the compile will accept it:

```
System.out.println(((C) a[2]).j); // compiles OK
```

Answer (score 2):

Every entry in your array `a` is of type `A`. It might actually be holding an instance of `B` or `C` or `D`, but the variable is of type `A`, because that is how your array was declared. So you can't access fields that `A` doesn't have (unless you cast to another type, telling the compiler explicitly what type you think the object is).